# PHP tot MySQL image uploading not working

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm trying to make a site in which I can upload a file to my sql database, but it does not seem to work.

This is my code;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload an image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
                <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            File:
            <input type="file" name="Image">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
        <?php
                    //Connecting to the database
                    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
                    mysql_select_db("picturedatabase") or die(mysql_error());

                    $file = $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'];

                    if(!isset($file))
                    {
                        echo "Select an image";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name']));
                        $image_name = addslashes($FILES['Image']['name']);
                        $image_size = getimagesize($FILES['Image']['tmp_name']);
                    }

                    if($image_size==FALSE)
                    {
                        echo "That's not an image.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO images VALUES('','$image_name','$image')"))
                       {
                           echo "There was a problem uploading the image";
                       }
                       else
                       {
                          $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
                          echo "Image uploaded!<p />Your image:<p /> <img src=show.php?id=$lastid>";
                       } 
                    }
                ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And when I run the file, the form stuff shows up (the buttons and I can also select a file), but it also says

```
"Notice: Undefined index: Image in C:\ProgramFiles\Xampp\htdocs\Database\upload.php on line 16
Notice: Undefined variable: image_size in C:\ProgramFiles\Xampp\htdocs\Database\upload.php on line 29"
```

Could someone tell me what I did wrong and help me fix this?

Comment: you're not testing if the form was submitted before trying to access `$_FILES`, if the form wasn't submitted then `$_FILES` is empty then you get undefined index. Additionally is that code the code of `upload.php`? cause you're submitting your form to `upload.php`

Comment: I already managed to find out that there's no programs in upload.php so I didnt post it here. Also, thanks! I totally forgot to check wether I had pressed submit! [EDIT] Actually, I have it check if it's not pressed, and then I got an else statement, which does something if it is sent.

Answer (score 2):

You should save the files in some folder during the upload process and save the name of file in database, so later you can call the name of file from database and link it as a hyperlink to download, i am using the following code to upload images in a folder called `files` and saving the name of files in database. At the end i have the file name in variable `$newname`

```
    if ($_FILES['file']['name']) {

        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 500000)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
        ) {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            } else {
                $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
                $filename = current(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
                $newname = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                    "files/" . $newname);
            }
        } else {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Image type or size is not valid.</div>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't really need to do that right? Right now I got it to display the temporary image

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Upload an image</title>
        </head>
        <body>
    <?php
    function output_errors($error) {
        echo '<ul><li><font color="red">'.$error.'</font>/li></ul>';
    }

    if($_POST) {
        //Connecting to the database
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" ,"", "picturedatabase");
        $name = $_FILES['Image']['name'];

        if(!empty($name)) {
            $tmp = $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'];
            $type = $_FILES['Image']['type'];

            $allowed_type = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png');

            if(!in_array($type, $allowed_type)) {
                $error[] = $type. ' is not allowed file type';
            }
        } else {
            $error[] = 'There are empty fields';
        }

        if(!empty($error)) {
            echo output_errors($error);
        } else if(empty($error)){
            $path = 'images/'.$name;

            $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `images` (`image`) VALUES ('$path')");

            if(!$query) {
                echo 'Insert into db went wrong';
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);
                echo '<font color="green">Upload succesful</font>';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
            <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                File:
                <input type="file" name="Image">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```