# How to uploading multiple files (images) and inserting into database and call to display back?

Tags: php, database, upload

> I want to insert my image files(multiple file) into my database(testproject) that have as >the follow field (imgid,img_name,img_small,img_large) but I can only upload only one file,
>   so how can I do it(insert into database and read in back to browser). thanks in advance for >any help.

Upload images

```
<body>
    <?php 
        mysql_connect("localhost","root")
            or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("testproject")
            or die (mysql_error());
    ?>

<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['btnadd'])){
        $imgname=$_POST['txtname'];
        $imgsname=$_FILES['imgs']['name'];
        $imgstemp=$_FILES['imgs']['tmp_name'];
        $imglname=$_FILES['imgl']['name'];
        $imgltemp=$_FILES['imgl']['tmp_name'];
            if(trim($imgname=='')){
                echo "Please input image name";
            }elseif(trim($imgsname=='')){
                echo "Please input small image";
            }elseif(trim($imglname=='')){
                echo "Please input large image";
            }else{
                $digit=rand();
                $imgsname=$digit."_".$imgsname;
                $imglname=$digit."_".$imglname;
                $sql="insert into tbl_images(imgid,img_name,img_small,img_large)
                value('','$imgname','$imgsname','$imglname')";
                $query=mysql_query($sql);
                if($query){
                        move_uploaded_file($imgstemp,"imgsmall/".$imgsname);
                        move_uploaded_file($imgltemp,"imglarge/".$imglname);
                        echo "Success";

                    }else{
                        echo mysql_error();
                        }               
                }       
        }       
?>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Image name <input type="text" name="txtname" /><br/>
        Upload small image <input type="file" name="imgs" multiple /><br/>
        Upload large image <input type="file" name="imgl" multiple /><br/>
                    <input type="submit" name="btnadd" value="Add"/><br/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326248/uploading-files/22326834#22326834

Comment: you have to insert the file path into database and retrieve the path and display the image

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269199/php-tot-mysql-image-uploading-not-working/22269447#22269447

Comment: Don't just link other link, pls show me how it work. Because I don't find out any help yet.